# Ruby on Rails 3 .each do Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I'm sort of new to Ruby on Rails and have been learning just fine, but have seem to run into a problem that I can't seem to solve.

Running Rails 3.0.9 & Ruby 1.9.2

I'm running the following statement in my View:

```
<%= @events.each do |f| %>
    <%= f.name %><%= link_to "View", event_path(f) %><br/><hr/>
<% end %>
```

And this in my controller:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def flyers
    @events = Event.all
  end
end
```

This goes through each of the records and outputs the appropriate name, but the problem is that at the end it displays all of the information for all of the records like so:

```
    [#<User id: 1, username: "test account", email: "test@gmail.com", password_hash:    "$2a$10$Rxwgy.0ZEOb0lMGEIliPBeB/jPSp8roeKdbMvXcLi32R...", password_salt: "$2a$10$Rxwgy.0ZEOb0lMGEIliPBe", created_at: 2111359287.2303703, updated_at: 2111359287.2303703, isadmin: true>]
```

I'm new to this site, so I'm not sure if you need any more details, but any help is appreciated, after all, I'm still learning.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

You should be using `<%`, not `<%=` for your `.each` line, so

```
<%= @events.each do |f| %>
```

should be

```
<% @events.each do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 9):

`.each` returns the entire array at the end once it is finished the loop. 
`<%= ... %>` prints out the value of the statment, which is the value returned by `.each`
`<% ... %>` does not. So you want:

```
<% @events.each do |f| %>
    <%= f.name %><%= link_to "View", event_path(f) %><br/><hr/>
<% end %>
```