# Undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass with `order` and `limit` in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a simple list of top 10 `users` ranked on the variable `manpoints` (a column in my `users` table), but keep getting:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Here's my `erb`:

```
  <h1 class="text-center">Manliest Men</h1>
    <ol>
      <%= @manliest_men.each do |user| %>
        <li><%= user.first_name %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ol>
```

And here's my controller for the `index` page where that `erb` lives:

```
  def index
    render layout: 'nofooter'
    @manliest_men = User.order("manpoints DESC").limit(10)
  end
```

I feel like this is fairly simple, but I can't figure out where I went wrong.  Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946206/ruby-on-rails-3-each-do-problem)

**Quoting @Dylan Markow**

You should be using <%, not <%= for your .each line, so

```
<%= @manliest_men.each do |user| %>
```

should be

```
<% @manliest_men.each do |user| %>
```

---

Edit:

The actual problem was in the controller, particularly the order:

```
def index
    render layout: 'nofooter'
    @manliest_men = User.order("manpoints DESC").limit(10)
end
```

Should be:

```
def index
    @manliest_men = User.order("manpoints DESC").limit(10)
    render layout: 'nofooter'
end
```

Comment: Excellent catch, but it unfortunately didn't fix the error.

Comment: Yeah, same error on this line: `<% @manliest_men.each do |user| %>`

Comment: Try switching places between `render layout: 'nofooter'` and
    `@manliest_men = User.order("manpoints DESC").limit(10)` .

Comment: Oh my goodness, it was the order.  That is so ridiculous.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad to help, to be honest I know nothing of Ruby/Ruby on Rails, I'm with C++/Java. But glad to help. If you don't mind could I ask you a few questions about Ruby? I'm kinda interested in it. Edit: Oh wait, I can't... I have my email address written on my page just in case.

Comment: Ruby is extremely interesting, but I am the wrong person to teach it.  I'm still firmly in the "newbie" category.